# How to add spellcheck dictionaries to Kile without being the root?

Tags: kile

I am needing to add the spanish dictionary to spellcheck in Kile, but I am not the root, then the installation using synaptic is not an option. I am using ubuntu 12.04 and the Aspell program that is implemented by defeault in this distribution. I downloaded the spanish dictionary for aspell (aspell-es) from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/es/ and I installed it in my home folder.

But now, how I can link Kile with this aspell-es installed in my home folder?

Comment: Does it not show up as an option? Where did you install it exactly?

Comment: @cfr I installed it the dictionary in /home/glara. Kile does not show an option to select the dictionary from an arbitrary folder.

Comment: It probably expects to find dictionaries in a particular place and not just anywhere in your home directory. Does Ubuntu use `enchant` for spelling? For example, on my system, user dictionaries are stored in `~/.config/enchant` though I only have customisations here as the main dictionaries are installed system-wide. (`aspell` is probably being used as a backend for `enchant` although it could be used independently.) See `man enchant` for details.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because KDE works in mysterious ways. I would suggest to move this to https://askubuntu.com/